# Are there other search options for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, full-text-search, hosting, pg-search

I am about to launch a beta site, and **heroku** looks like a great option.  The only think that is getting me down is that the only search option is $20/mth for the Websolr add-on.

I am sure that Websolr is great, but at this very early point in this project, I rather not light up that expense.

Are there any free search options to couple with **heroku**'s Blossom (free) plan.

I feel like such a cheapskate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post seems to have good options:

Leveraging the full text search of postgrSQL:

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/10/17/full-text-search-on-heroku.html

Also explains the options of Ferret and Solr.

Answer (score 4):

IndexTank has a heroku addon you can use for free.

It has some advantages over websolr, like realtimeness, fast (all in ram), and a very flexible scoring system that doesn't require to reindex (allows for very easy a/b testing).

Comment: I've been having good luck with IndexTank. It's quick and easy to get started. There's a nicely maintained interface gem at https://github.com/kidpollo/tanker

Comment: I just searched Heroku's plugins and I don't think this exists any more.

Answer (score 2):

My gem [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) does full-text search against PostgreSQL, and works directly on Heroku.

Check it out and let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

acts_as_tsearch works great. No configuration needed if you have postgresql > 8.3. Have to experiment with multiple tables though. Will use it on heroku till i can afford the WebSolr Add-on. I found it a better option compared to the texticle method as explained in the article link above (tendermaking).

acts_as_tsearch: http://github.com/pka/acts_as_tsearch

Answer (score 0):

No, I was looking for that too a week ago, and didn't find anything...
And I don't think there is any work in progress on another add-ons like this as they already have one, so they won't put another that is free... :/
Anyway, heroku is amazing, so try to make it work with code or just spend $20 :)

Comment: Then I guess the followup question.  Are they any 'in-rails' full text serach options.  Thanks

Comment: There is [ferret](http://railsenvy.com/2007/2/19/acts-as-ferret-tutorial), but I'm not sure this will work... Try post the results :)

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_ferret won't work as Heroku cleans up the /tmp directory regularly. Even i am in need of a full-text solution. Thinking of trying out the acts_as_tsearch plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IndexTank was purchased by LinkedIn and will be discontinuing support (although some portions might be open-sourced in the future).  See this post for more info: https://indextank.com/documentation/faq2

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres for your Rails app then take a look at this free way to do full text search:

[Part 1](http://www.codosaur.us/2012/09/free-full-text-search-with-heroku-part-1.html) and 
[Part 2](http://www.codosaur.us/2012/09/free-full-text-search-with-heroku-part-2.html)

This uses the `pg_search` gem to allow you to use PostgreSQL's `pg_search_scopes` feature and have full text search without any other dependencies.